# Is it possible to have multiple values for ONE label in non-queried available values in SSRS 2005?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

Parameters - Multiple Values For One Label - Is it Possible?

Is it possible to have multiple values for ONE label in one row in non-queried parameter value, 
so that i can have ONE LABEL in Drop-down List for multiple values.

Basically if i write single value for each label then it works fine but the problem is when i run the report it shows me check-box for each name. It does not look nice for the user to tick and select all values for Site-1 like nine or ten values. Where as ideally it should be one label and multiple values (which i want).

Works Fine: (But this bring a long list in drop down menu since i have more value for site-1, which i do not want)

```
Label                Value
---------------------------
Site-1                 150
Site-1                 151
Site-1                 152
Site-1                 160 
Site-2                 161
Site-2                 162
```

and in query `ColumnName IN (@Site)` works fine too.

Required result (In one line so that drop down menu should give only two labels)

```
Label                Value
---------------------------
Site-1                 150,151,152,160
Site-2                 161,162
```

which will bring one label and related multi-value in drop down or combo box, and in query `ColumnName IN (@Site)` DOES NOT work.

Sorry. Site is a column name in DB and @Site is a variable name.

Site-1 & Site-2 are label names for drop down menu.

Comment: Thanks Ken White for the editing. Hopefully i will learn gradually as how to post precisely. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is your database sees your comma-separated values as a normal string when you pass it as a parameter, so it doesn't know what to do with `'150,151,152,160'` when it's expecting an int.

A good general way to handle this is by creating a table-valued function that returns a table when you pass in your comma-separated string.  The easiest way I've found is [Erland Sommarskog's Arrays and Lists in SQL Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html):

```
CREATE FUNCTION split_csv (@list nvarchar(MAX))
   RETURNS @tbl TABLE (number int NOT NULL) AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @pos        int,
           @nextpos    int,
           @valuelen   int

   SELECT @pos = 0, @nextpos = 1

   WHILE @nextpos > 0
   BEGIN
      SELECT @nextpos = charindex(',', @list, @pos + 1)
      SELECT @valuelen = CASE WHEN @nextpos > 0
                              THEN @nextpos
                              ELSE len(@list) + 1
                         END - @pos - 1
      INSERT @tbl (number)
         VALUES (convert(int, substring(@list, @pos + 1, @valuelen)))
      SELECT @pos = @nextpos
   END
   RETURN
END
```

Then using the above function, that line in your query becomes:

```
ColumnName IN (SELECT number FROM split_csv(@Site))
```

If you are using SQL Server 2008+, you can use table-valued parameters instead which are even simpler.  I'll refer you to the same [Erland Sommarskog site](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html) for info on that.

Comment: thanks for your reply!! but I just found the alternate to this problem which is by using SPLIT() Function. Its working fine. I am feeling on the moon now :)